# Is there a way to enter descriptions for each table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In SQL Server there are extended properties to enter a 'description' for each table.

Is there an equivalent in MYSQL? If so, can I access from PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add comments for a table in phpMyAdmin, choose the table, `Operations` -> `Table Operations` -> `Table comments`.

Related sql:

```
ALTER TABLE  `MyTableName` COMMENT =  'My Comment'
```

Comment: Perfect... I need a course in 'googling'. It never occurred to me to search for 'comment'.